# Show pages based on authentication roles in Durandal SPA, MVC web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, durandal, simple-authentication

what i'm trying to do is lock down certain pages in my durandal(knockoutjs/breezejs) SPA app based on a user's authenticated role (ie, if you're an admin, etc, you should see pages that others shouldn't).

ideally, server code could be used to either output the link or not based on role, but since durandal and SPA apps don't really work that way with server code, i'm at a loss.

i realize this question has been asked in other forms here (i.e. how to use .cshtml (server) pages with Durandal), and this could be an option if perhaps i could get it to work. i have yet to find a very complete example that works for me.

any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your routing information on the server and supply it to the application on initialization.

For example. In the activate method of your shell viewmodel

shell.js

```
define(['durandal/system', 'plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'services/datacontext'],
    function (system, router, app, datacontext) {

        var routeInfo = ko.observable();

        var shell = {
            activate: activate,
            router: router

        };

        return shell;

        //#region Internal Methods
        function activate() {
            app.title = "Sample App";
            return boot();
        }

        function boot() {
            return datacontext.getRouteInformation(routeInfo).then(function() {
                return router.map(routeInfo()).buildNavigationModel().mapUnknownRoutes('error', 'Error').activate();
            });
        }
        //#endregion
    });
```

my datacontext.getRouteInformation() gets a json array of route information based on the current users security context and populates the routeInfo observable. that observable is then passed to the map function to create the users valid routes etc.

I know this doesn't fully "lock down" the html files etc, but all of my controllers and actions have authorization attributes on them, so the data is protected.

Comment: that's a good idea, @Excommunicated, and one i haven't seen presented yet. i'll give it a shot. and my controllers/actions are also locked down in this manner, but i wanted that additional level of 'security'. question: so, if someone figures out a 'link' that they're not authorized to see, it will show the 'error' page in your example, correct? thanks!

Comment: correct. For example if they try to go to http://mysite.com/Admin and they are not an administrator, I redirect to the error page, but you can redirect them home or anywhere you like.. What this doesn't stop is someone going to http://mysite.com/app/views/admin.html. but my html contains nothing other than raw HTML and data-bind attributes, so nothing of value.

Comment: actually, since durandal mainly uses the concept of an API or REST methods, what controller/actions exactly do you have locked down? i have my API methods locked down, but really that's just locking down the data, not the navigation to the pages themselves.

Comment: sorry, one more thing is that i have my routes configured in the main.js, not shell.js. this was the default when i installed durandal.

Comment: you can do them wherever you like. I personally did the routes in the shell as it's where I call activate on the router, so I pump in the routes then activate. Just my preference. but main.js should work too.

Comment: ah ok. and i just realized my durandal is out of date. it will take some doing to get it up to current. lol.

Comment: @Excommunicated is there a git version of this where we can see the source code and run the app in Vs?

Comment: @kougiland Of this example, no, this was based on a proprietary project I was doing for a client. sorry. But I should work on this when I get some time..

Comment: @Excommunicated   check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186048/route-and-subroute-based-on-user-in-hottowel-asp-net-mvc4